# bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile function remove context

Tags: python

```
import os
import bpy 
import json
import numpy as np
from mathutils import Matrix; 
from math import *
from glob import glob
RESOLUTION = 512
SAMPLES = 64
BOUNCES = 1
ROOT_DIR = "/Users/cmh/Desktop/blender/nvdiffrecmc"

scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.world.use_nodes = True
scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
scene.render.film_transparent = True
scene.cycles.device = 'GPU'
scene.cycles.samples = SAMPLES
scene.cycles.max_bounces = BOUNCES
scene.cycles.diffuse_bounces = BOUNCES
scene.cycles.glossy_bounces = BOUNCES
scene.cycles.transmission_bounces = 0
scene.cycles.volume_bounces = 0
scene.cycles.transparent_max_bounces = 8
scene.cycles.use_denoising = True

scene.render.resolution_x = RESOLUTION
scene.render.resolution_y = RESOLUTION
scene.render.resolution_percentage = 100

# OpenEXR output, should not be tonemapped
scene.display_settings.display_device = 'None'
scene.view_settings.view_transform = 'Standard'
scene.view_settings.exposure = 0.0
scene.view_settings.gamma = 1.0
scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'OPEN_EXR' 

scene.view_layers['ViewLayer'].use_pass_combined=True
scene.view_layers['ViewLayer'].use_pass_diffuse_direct=True
scene.view_layers['ViewLayer'].use_pass_diffuse_color=True
scene.view_layers['ViewLayer'].use_pass_glossy_direct=True
scene.view_layers['ViewLayer'].use_pass_glossy_color=True

DATASET = "nerf" # "nerfactor"

def relight_scene(SCENE):
    MESH_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "blend_files")
    PROBE_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "data/irrmaps", DATASET)
    RESULTS_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "relight_gt", DATASET, SCENE)

    os.makedirs(RESULTS_PATH, exist_ok=True)

    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="SELECT")
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

    ################### Import mesh ###################
    
    imported_object = bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=os.path.join(MESH_PATH, SCENE + ".blend"))

    ################### Load HDR probe ###################

    # Common setup
    with open(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, f"data/nerf_synthetic/{SCENE}/transforms_val.json"), 'r') as f:
        val_cfg = json.load(f)

    camera_data   = bpy.data.cameras.new(name='Camera')
    camera_object = bpy.data.objects.new('Camera', camera_data)
    scene.collection.objects.link(camera_object)
    scene.camera  = camera_object
    camera_data.angle = val_cfg['camera_angle_x']

    # load all probes

    for file in glob(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, PROBE_PATH, DATASET, "*.hdr")):
        envmap = scene.world.node_tree.nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeTexEnvironment")
        envmap.image = bpy.data.images.load(file)
        scene.world.node_tree.links.new(envmap.outputs[0], scene.world.node_tree.nodes['Background'].inputs['Color'])

        for i in range(8):
            mtx = np.array(val_cfg['frames'][i]['transform_matrix'], dtype=np.float32)
            scene.camera.matrix_world = Matrix(mtx)
            scene.render.filepath = os.path.join(RESULTS_PATH, os.path.basename(file)[:-4] + '_r_{0:03d}'.format(int(i)))
            bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)  # render still 

relight_scene(SCENE="chair")
```

And it gives this error.

```
Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cmh/Desktop/blender/nvdiffrecmc/relight_base.py", line 86, in <module>
    relight_scene(SCENE="chair")
  File "/Users/cmh/Desktop/blender/nvdiffrecmc/relight_base.py", line 69, in relight_scene
    scene.collection.objects.link(camera_object)
ReferenceError: StructRNA of type Scene has been removed
```

It seems that bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile function removes scene predefined above and I can't find related information in the document. Any help please?

Comment: Replace all occurrences of `scene` with `bpy.context.scene`. Storing a pointer to a blender object is not advised because they can be invalidated semi-randomly (on load, on save, on undo, etc.). This will have no noticeable impact on performance unless you run your script on hundreds of thousands (if not more) of files which at this point you'll have other types of bottlenecks to handle. :)